# Wemos D1 404 Not Found - but it is there

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I am trying to connect my Wemos D1 to a website to get some data, but I am getting a 404 Not Found Error. I made sure that the url is correct, but I am stilling getting errors. I looked at the errors in the log, but they are empty.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


const char* ssid     = "SSID";      // SSID of local network
const char* password = "xxxxx";   // Password on network
String APIKEY = "xxxx";

WiFiClient client;
char servername[]="notreal.com";  // fake host for sample
String result;

int readKey;
int count;
int cursorPosition;

int button;
int x = 0;
void setup() {
  //Setup Serial
  Serial.begin(9600);


  //Connecting to server and get current temperature and set temperature
  lcd.print("   Connecting");  
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("NOT CONNECTED");
    lcd.setCursor(cursorPosition,2); 
    lcd.print(".");
    cursorPosition++;
  }

  getData();
  //Serial.println("Connected");*/
  delay(1000);

}

void loop() {

    //Do Something
  }

void getData() //client function to send/receive GET request data.
{
  if (client.connect(servername, 80)) {  //starts client connection, checks for connection
    client.println("GET /data/getData.php?API="+APIKEY);
    client.println("HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: notreal.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed"); //error message if no client connect
    Serial.println();
  }

  while(client.connected() && !client.available()) delay(1); //waits for data
  while (client.connected() || client.available()) { //connected or data available
    char c = client.read(); //gets byte from ethernet buffer
      result = result+c;
    }

  client.stop(); //stop client
  result.replace('[', ' ');
  result.replace(']', ' ');
  Serial.println(result);

}
```

This is what I get in the serial:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /nest/getTemp.php was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

This is in the error log:

```
[host.com] [Fri Aug 05 03:57:33 2016] [error] [client 24.28.29.44] client denied by server configuration: /home/domains/host.com/.htaccess
```

I checked the server setting and according to support, everything should be set for remote access.

Comment: It might not be a problem, but http version should be on the same line with get:  `GET /something HTTP/1.1`

Comment: thanks for the advice, but i changed my code to acccess openweather.org and i was able to download weather data via their api. i am not sure why, but my server is rejecting the wemos client only.. i can remotely access the server with an android device, but for some reason the server is rejecting.. is there some code to diagnosis the connection?

Comment: try to get any other resource on that server, but first make sure you can get it with the PostMan - app for Chrome. that should provide some insights if the problem is in the server or in your calls. Also make sure you aren't using a proxy on your PC.